# Expo EAS Build not generating QR code from react-native-qrcode-svg

Tags: react-native, expo, qr-code, eas

I am trying to generate a QR Code in my React Native Expo application. I am using the react-native-qrcode-svg npm module. When I am running the code locally (using the Expo Go App) everything works completely fine. But when I build the app with EAS and test the app on TestFlight the app will crash, giving no error.

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run config:localAndDev && expo start --clear",
    "publish": "npm run config:prod && eas update --branch production --message 'Updating the app'",
    "build:ios:prod": "npm run config:prod && eas build --platform ios",
    "build:all:prod": "npm run config:prod && eas build --platform all",
    "build:android:prod": "npm run config:prod && eas build --platform android",
    "submit:ios": "eas submit --platform ios",
    "submit:android": "eas submit --platform android",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "config:localAndDev": "node scripts/set-configuration.js localAndDevelopment",
    "config:prod": "node scripts/set-configuration.js production",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "run:ios:prod": "npm run config:prod && expo run:ios",
    "run:android:prod": "npm run config:prod && expo run:android"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.2",
    "@rneui/base": "edge",
    "@rneui/themed": "edge",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.13.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-plugin-inline-dotenv": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables": "^0.4.3",
    "expo": "^46.0.7",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~4.3.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.6.1",
    "expo-auth-session": "^3.7.1",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-battery": "~6.3.0",
    "expo-camera": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.2.3",
    "expo-firebase-analytics": "~7.1.1",
    "expo-google-sign-in": "^11.0.0",
    "expo-linking": "~3.2.2",
    "expo-location": "~14.3.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.16.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~13.2.0",
    "expo-random": "^12.3.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-task-manager": "~10.3.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.14.4",
    "expo-web-browser": "^11.0.0",
    "firebase": "^9.9.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.3",
    "native-base": "^3.4.12",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "^0.69.4",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.11.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-expo-viewport-units": "^0.0.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-grid-image-viewer": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.9.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6"
  },
  "private": true,
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Let me know if you need more info.